# how to trigger a data bricks jobs using YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-databricks, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-yaml, databricks-workflows

how can I trigger any data bricks job using Yaml? I have a job1.json file saved in the repo which has jobId like this:

```
{
  "Job_ID": "12345678910"
}
```

So far I've this but I'm getting an error running this code:

```
  
  - name: configu
    value: 'rel'
  - name: Bld1
    value: 'test'
  - name: BHP
    value: '1.1'
  trigger:
    none
  stages:
  - stage: Bld
    jobs:
    - job: Bld
      displayName: AG
      pool:
        vmImage: windows-****
      steps:
      - checkout: self
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: $(build.sourcesdirectory)
          Contents: '*\'
          TargetFolder: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        displayName: 'Publish : $(buildParameters.artifactName)'
        inputs:
          path: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
          artifactName: $(buildParameters.artifactName)
- stage: Dev
    variables:
      - group: abc
      - group: def
    jobs:
    - job: RunDatabricksJob
      displayName: 'Run Databricks Job'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-****'
      steps:
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'test1'
          scriptType: 'bash'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
              token=$(az account get-access-token \
              --resource akbfksjfwfkjvjkrbfj \
              --query "accessToken" \
              --output tsv)
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=azureadtoken;isoutput=true]$token"
        name: tokengen
      - task: PythonScript@0
      - script: |
          job_id=$(python -c "import json; print(json.load(open('$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/../$(BuildParameters.ArtifactName)/job1.json'))['job_id'])")
          databricks jobs run-now --job-id $job_id
        env:
          DATABRICKS_HOST: $(hostname)
          DATABRICKS_TOKEN: $(tokengen.azureadtoken)
```

Could you you please suggest correct methd to trigger job or what's wrong with this code?

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So far I've this but I'm getting an error running this code:

Could you share the error message?

From looking at your sample code, could you please check the following?

1 .Please check if there is an uppercase and lowercase spelling error on `Job_ID`.

```
json.load(open('xxx/xxx/job1.json'))['job_id'])
```

2 Please check if you define a variable `job_id` in python with `$`. A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (A-z, 0-9, and _ ).If so ,please remove `$` character.

3 Please check if there is `-` in front of `script`.

sample:

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    script: |
      import  json
      job_id =json.load(open('$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/../$(BuildParameters.ArtifactName)/job1.json'))['Job_ID'])
      # print job_id
      print(job_id)
      databricks jobs run-now --job-id job_id
```

Hope it can help.

**UPDATE**

You can use both  Databricks CLI and REST API to trigger a job. Here is an example to run a databirck job with Databricks CLI in YAML pipeline.

1.Install the CLI

```
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.7'
    addToPath: true
    architecture: 'x64'
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'pip install databricks-cli'
```

2 Set up authentication using a Microsoft Entra ID (formerly Azure Active Directory) token

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo $token > token-file
      databricks configure --host $url --token-file token-file
```

Note: You can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/user-aad-token) to get tokens.

3.use `PythonScript@0` task to get job_id

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      import  json
      job_id =json.load(open('$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/job1.json'))['job_id']
       print(f'##vso[task.setvariable variable={job_id};]{job_id}')
```

4 use Databricks CLI to run job

```
 - task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
     databricks jobs run-now --job-id job-id
```

Doc referred:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/archive/dev-tools/cli/

Comment: I checked all your points. All job_id is in lowercase including from the job1.json file.
I've removed $ and - as well.
Still, I'm getting the same error. I think this task is expecting the .py file to execute instead .json

https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/python-script
2023-11-14T13:40:32.5300385Z ==============================================================================
2023-11-14T13:40:32.7608838Z ##[error]The given path was not to a file: 'D:\a\1\s'.
2023-11-14T13:40:32.7620447Z ##[section]Finishing: Trigger Databricks Job

Comment: Should I use data bricks REST API to trigger a job?
`
- script: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y curl
          response=$(curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(db_token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
              -d '{
                    "job_id": "12345678910"
                  }' \
              https://$(db_host)/api/2.0/jobs/run-now)
        env:
          db_token: $(tokengen.azureadtoken)
          db_job_id: $(db_job_id)
          db_host: $(hostname)
        displayName: 'Trigger Databricks Job'
`